# how to query a layout via ODBC in Filemaker Database

Tags: c#, sql, odbc, filemaker

I have to access a **FileMaker DB** via **ODBC** in a C# application...

When querying database table, everything goes fine. However when it comes to query a layout named XYZ for instance (as far as I understood, layouts are some sort of SQL views, please correct me if I am wrong), application throws an error `indicating that _the table XYZ is not found_.`

I wonder if there is **any special keyword** to access a layout in the odbc command or         **any other way** to query layout via ODBC?..

I could not manage to find a source describing the accessibility of layouts via ODBC. I have a little knowledge about FileMaker, thus this question could be inappropriate, sorry for the inconvenience in advance.

Comment: my two cents are that ODBC is a standard connectivity bridge/protocol which supports only common objects and methods which are mostly available in many different databases, these layouts you are talking about seem to be specific of Filemaker so could be the ODBC driver does not support them because it has no way to translate/transfer those objects in anything meaningful on the other side of the driver. I know nothing about FileMaker, just a guess.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot access layouts via ODBC, only tables. Otherwise [here's the manual](http://www.filemaker.com/support/product/docs/fms/fm11_odbc_jdbc_guide_en.pdf) (PDF) on FileMaker ODBC SQL.